# Bootstrap form nested in Site.Master

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a Bootstrap `form-horizontal` in an .aspx page with a Site.Master page.

I get the error message that a form cannot be nested in another form.

I found several comments here that a Site.Master should not contain a form `runat=server` but every Visual Studio 2013 template I look at is set up that way and when I try to remove the form from the Site.Master I get an error:

> asp:ScriptManager must be nested in a form.

I like the Bootstrap forms. Any work arounds?

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest forms within forms in ASP.net. A Master Page will define the form tag and within that define a number of ContentPlaceHolders. Pages that then use the Master Page will then be have the option to place content within each of the defined place holders.

See [how ASP.Net Master Pages work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX#HowMasterPagesWork).

To use the BootStrap form-horizontal class just modify the Master Pages form tag e.g.

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server" class="form-horizontal">
```

You can of course have a selection of Master Pages (or nested Master Pages) to customise for each of your scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it using jQuery addClass for the .aspx page you need it for.

Use this on your individual pages.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form1").addClass("form-horizontal");
    });
</script>
```